# codeacademy "Functions & if/else"

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find an answer to why this returns an error. The other questions regarding this section of code academy had to do with missing or misplaced "{}" and missing or misplaced ";". I don't believe I am having that problem, but it is still returning an error.

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours)
{
    if (sleepCheck>8)
    {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else
    {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
};
sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `sleepCheck` is a function you are using it as a variable.
2. You need to use `numHours` parameter passed to function in `if` condition

***Code***

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
    if (numHours > 8) {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    } else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};
sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/jU94p/)

Answer (score 2):

In your if statement, you should be comparing the variable `numHours`, not the function name `sleepCheck` as you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours){
if (numHours>=8)
{
    return"You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
}
else {
    return"Get some more shut eye!";}       
}

sleepCheck(10);

sleepCheck(5);

sleepCheck(8);
```

Explanation: 1>you should be comparing the variable numHours not the function named sleepCheck.

**for example:**

```
var time = function(number){
    return number*2
};

var newNumber = time(10);

console.log(newNumber);
```

Will print out 20

So in this case, nobody will use  "return time*2", it does not make sense.  Instead, they use "return number*2".  The same idea as **if (numHours>=8)**  not  **if (sleepCheck>=8)**

```
2> is not "if (sleepCheck>8)", should be " if (numHours>=8)".
```

Hope I'm able to help you understand now.

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as how this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would tackle it. I am working in my local editor and console, so this example will give you the needed feedback when calling the function. It should satisfy the Codeacademy parameters.

```js
function sleepCheck(numHours) {
  return numHours >= 8
  ? "You're getting plenty of sleep!  Maybe even too much" 
  : "Get some more shut eye!";
};

console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

This examle is using an [inline conditional ternery operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Not all cases call for them but sometimes you will find great uses for them.
[Using function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Using_function)

Answer (score 0):

`sleepCheck` is function

```
  var sleepCheck = function (hrs)

     {

     if (hrs >= 8)

    {

     return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!" ;

     }

     else

     {

    return "Get some more shut eye!" ;

    }

    };

 sleepCheck(10);

 sleepCheck(5);

 sleepCheck(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sleepCheck(numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    } else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}
sleepCheck(10);
```

Comment: To make this answer useful, you need to explain exactly what you have 'fixed' with the code and why the original code was not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    } else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};
sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);

// this works now works on code academy as I added the correct symbol on if  numHours. however when copied and pasted make sure you get rid of anything before the first line of the actual code which starts with var. this sometimes appears in codeacademy when you paste the code.
```